# Use a custom install profile for Nightwatch tests?

Tags: 8, testing

How can you set a custom install profile to run a Nightwatch test in? I am not seeing it in the docs. The definition of the `.drupalInstall()` command has:

```
commandAsWebserver(
        `php ./scripts/test-site.php install ${setupFile} --install-profile nightwatch_testing --base-url ${process.env.DRUPAL_TEST_BASE_URL} ${dbOption} --json`,
      ),
```

Which looks like the profile is hardcoded with no way to set.

Answer (score 0):

As you understood it's been hardcoded. if you want to make it dynamic you can  create your custom parameter.

you can do it in a way like the following  :

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3017176

this patch help you to know what you can do : https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-11-11/3017176-16.patch

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get Nightwatch running regardless, it would not use my selenium container whereas the WebDriverTestBase tests in PHP work correctly. I've switched off to Cypress and it's working great.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your feedback and solution. I'll remember it. good idea!